Why does the narration shift between first-person and third-person in the short story "Tell them not to kill me!"?
In Juan Rulfo's short story "Tell them not to kill me!" (part of the collection The Burning Plain and Other Stories, of which George D. Schade's English translation is freely available to borrow from the Internet Archive), the narration is mostly in third person, but shifts abruptly to first-person narration and then back again in the middle of the story:

Until one day Don Lupe said to him, "Look here, Juvencio, if you let another animal in my pasture, I'll kill it."
And he answered him, "Look here, Don Lupe, it's not my fault that the animals look out for themselves. They're innocent. You'll have to pay for it, if you kill them."
And he killed one of my yearlings.
This happened thirty-five years ago in March, because in April I was already up in the mountains, running away from the summons.
[...]
Sometimes I had to go out at midnight, as though the dogs were after me. It's been that way my whole life. Not just a year or two. My whole life.
And now they've come for him when he no longer expected anyone, confident that people had forgotten about it, believing that he'd spend at least his last days peacefully.

(emphasis added by me)
There's no quote marks or italicisation around the first-person part (which is just five paragraphs), nor any gaps between paragraphs to indicate that this is a separate section with a different narration style (and there are gaps elsewhere, when the point of view shifts from his son to him and back again). It doesn't make the story hard to understand - I read it easily in one sitting, without needing to go back and figure out who's who, unlike in some other writing with odd narration choices - but it did strike me as odd, and I wondered what it adds to the story, or what the reason could be for this change back and forth. What's the point or effect of changing the narrator twice mid-story?
